# why doesn't this website scale properly on a smarthpone?

Tags: responsive-design, scale, viewport, screen-orientation

I'm busy developing a [portfolio website](http://haendehoch.nl/wp). This website should behave responsively, ie: the website should be fully displayed when browsing on smaller screens.

I have added the meta viewport tag, but it does not seem to work. At the moment you need to scroll horizontally to view the full content. I want it to be initially scaled to the width of the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I guess I am missing something, but no clue what..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having all kinds of problems with viewport. Finally I just removed all traces of that stupid thing, and everything seems to scale correctly now. It might be that current mobile browsers are smart enough to scale without use of viewport. Of course I am using media queries too.

Comment: it actually seems to be you should not apply the viewport meta-tag (with initial scale set to 1) when you are designing a non-responsive website: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design

Comment: Back to where I started. After removing that meta tag, scaling worked perfectly on my HTC Incredible droid phone as well as my iPad 2. I just got an iPhone 4S and found that removing that meta tag stop all responsiveness (on that device).

Comment: It's so frustrating I have played with everything that could be spilling over causing the browser to scale wider than it should. But it should just scale to 1.0 if that is how it is set, as in, the browser will shrink the site down based on the range of widths set in the media query. Instead it is setting the initial scale at like 1.2. I would think if any of my minimum widths were greater than the browser width for that media query that would happen, but not if my max widths are within the media query range. As a hack I set initial width to .8 and it sort of works.